# C: Recursively create child process possible?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, prime-factoring

I am trying to write a `Sieve of Eratosthenes` program in C, which I need to create a `child process` for each `prime number` less than or equal to the square root of the user input.

Since the total child process I need is not fixed, is it possible to create a `recursive function` which gonna create multiple child process if necessary? Or is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Considering the sheer number of primes and the fact that each process will be inheriting a self-copy of a table only their children will ever utilize, I wouldn't do this with forked processes at all. You could use shared mem, but at that point you may as well just use pthreads. And a multi-threaded e-sieve is anything but trivial, so no matter which way you go its going to take a little planning.

Comment: The best way to implement this surely is not to fork() a new process for each prime. The cost of creating a new process is quite high. A lightweight thread might be usable here, though you probably don't want to run more threads than you have processor cores. While you're at optimizing, consider using Sieve of Atkin instead of Sieve of Erastothenes.